# creating a wordpress plugin using zend framework compoments

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework2, zend-db

I was wondering if there is a way to create a WordPress plugin that is built on ZF2.
If there is a way please elaborate how to include it in my plugin.
Or if there are some good tutorial over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take help of composer here. 
import zf2 library thorough composer and use it in your plugin as part of plugin code.